# rearrange SQL data to different view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with product, salesvolume, date and a timestamp in SQL server.

I have data in tables as:

date     product time    volume
10-28-2014      a   15:05   5
10-28-2014      a   16:06   8
10-28-2014      b   9:05    3

Required format:

date        product h10 h16 h17
"10-28-2014"    a       5   8
"10-28-2014"    b   3

From this I want to create a new table/view in which I have total sales per day, per product, per hour of the day.

So i'll have 24 columns, 1 per hour of the day and one record for every day for every product.

Is this possible to create with just SQL? any tips how to do this?

Thank you!

I'm sorry but can't get the table layout to work...

Comment: Yes it's possible. Also, your understanding of a database is confusing (probably you meant a table inside database). Is it a good practice? That's definitely debatable. "We" have queries to build results like this. View would be appropriate.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I meant a table inside a sql server database. What isn't good practice? And what do you mean by we? thank you!

Comment: why these downvotes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first of all group  your data by day, hour (which you can extract from your time-stamp field), product and sum by sales.

From this you can then use the pivot function to cross-tab your hour field - you'll find plenty of documentation about the pivot functionality on-line.